# Zombie views and events in Backbone marionette layout... Have I got them?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I think I might have a problem with zombie views in my Backbone Marionette app.

1. How can I check for unclosed views and memory leaks?  I'm using the illuminations-for-developers.com add-on for Firefox and as I move around my application I see over 1000 views piling up in the 'widgets' illuminations tab - and when I inspect the HTML for them the majority are not in the DOM. Are these zombied views?
2. Have added the code I'm using below to get peoples opinion on if I'm attacking the problem the right way.

I'm trying to build a UI similar to the Facebook multiple friend selector dialog (see pic).

I have a layout with two collection views, one populated with a list of users, and an empty one in which the selected users are added to.

I want to use this layout in multiple areas of my app. So I have built a controller object that handles initializing it and loading the data for the collections, and then I initialize it and show it in another region whenever it is required.

Would appreciate tips on how to go about this, thanks.

Codez:

MyApp.UserFilterController

```
MyApp.UserFilterController = (function(){
var UserFilterController = {};
var selectedUsersCol;
var userFilterColView;
var selectedUsersColView;
var usersCol;

UserFilterController.initialize = function ( callback, excludeUsers ) {
    // make a query...
    // exclude the users...
    var usersQ = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    // just users with email addresses
    usersQ.exists('email');
    usersQ.exists('name');
    usersQ.limit(1000);
    usersQ.ascending('name');
    usersQ.notContainedIn('objectId',excludeUsers);
    usersCol = usersQ.collection();
    // tell it where to render... append to the body give it an element?

    userFilterColView = new MyApp.UserFilterUserCollectionView({
        collection:usersCol
    });

    usersCol.fetch({
        success:function (col) {
            console.log("users collection fetched", col.length);
        },
        error:function () {
            console.log("error fetching users collection");
        }
    });

    $('#subpage-header').text("Users Selection");

    // empty collection to hold the selected users
    selectedUsersCol = new MyApp.Users();
    // view to show the selected users
    selectedUsersColView = new MyApp.SelectedUserCollectionView({
        collection:selectedUsersCol
    });
    _.extend(selectedUsersCol, newBackboneAddMethod());

    MyApp.userFilterLayout = new MyApp.UserFilterLayout();

    MyApp.slideUp.content.show(MyApp.userFilterLayout);

    MyApp.userFilterLayout.selectedusers.show(selectedUsersColView);
    MyApp.userFilterLayout.allusers.show(userFilterColView);

    //When user clicks on user in all users then its added to selected users
    userFilterColView.on("itemview:clicked", function(childView, model){
        console.log(model);
        selectedUsersCol.add(model);
    });


    userFilterColView.on("collection:rendered", function(childView, model){
        console.log('its rendered');
    });

    //When user clicks on selected user then it is removed from the collection
    selectedUsersColView.on("itemview:clicked", function(childView, model){
        console.log(model);
        console.log(model.id);
        selectedUsersCol.remove(model);
    });

    MyApp.App.vent.bind("slideUp:send",function(){
        console.log("send button has been clicked. attempting call back")
        callback(selectedUsersCol);
    });

    //unbinds the trigger above when view is being closed
    userFilterColView.on('collection:before:close', function (){
        MyApp.App.vent.unbind("slideUp:send");
        console.log('colView before:close')
    });
};

UserFilterController.removeUser = function ( user ) {
    //console.log("you asked to remove", usersArray.length, 'users');
    selectedUsersCol.remove(user);
    usersCol.remove(user);
};
UserFilterController.generateListview = function ( user ) {
    userFilterColView.$el.listview();
};
UserFilterController.resetSelected = function (user) {
    selectedUsersCol.reset();
};
UserFilterController.cleanup = function () {
    console.log("its closing");
    //selectedUsersColView.unbindAll();
    //        selectedUsersColView.close();
    userFilterColView.close();
   // userFilterLayout.unbindAll();
    //        MyApp.userFilterLayout.close();
    //        MyApp.slideUp.content.close();
   // MyApp.slideUp.close();
};

return UserFilterController;
}());
```

MyApp.EventDisplayLayout

```
MyApp.EventDisplayLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: '#event-display-layout',
    id: "EventDisplayLayout",

    events: {
        'click #invite':  'showUserFilter'        
    },

    // User clicked on 'invite' button
    showUserFilter: function () {        
        $.mobile.changePage($('#subpage'), {changeHash: false,transition: 'slideup'});
        MyApp.UserFilterController.generateListview();
    }
}
```

MyApp.showEventDisplay

```
MyApp.showEventDisplay = function (event) {
var eventDisplayLayout = new MyApp.EventDisplayLayout({});
MyApp.App.mainRegion.show(eventDisplayLayout);    

var Invitees = event.get("invitees");
var excludeIds = [];
_.each(Invitees,function(invitee){
    excludeIds.push(invitee.id);
});
MyApp.UserFilterController.initialize(function (selectUsersCol){
    console.log("In call back: ",selectUsersCol);
},excludeIds);
};
```

MyApp.SlideUpPageLayout

```
// The generic layout used for modal panel sliding up from bottom of page.
MyApp.SlideUpPageLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    el: '#subpage',
    //template: '#homepage-temp',
    regions: {
        header: '.header',
        content: '.content'
    },
    events:{
        'click .send':'slideUpSend',
        'click .cancel':'slideUpCancel'
    },
    onShow: function () {
        console.log("SlideUpPage onShow");
        this.$el.trigger('create');
    },
    initialize: function () {
        // make user collection...

    },
    slideUpSend: function () {
        console.log("send button has been pressed");
        MyApp.App.vent.trigger('slideUp:send');
        $.mobile.changePage($('.type-home'),{transition: 'slideup',reverse:true});
    },
    slideUpCancel: function () {
   //     MyApp.App.vent.trigger('slideUp:cancel');
        $.mobile.changePage($('.type-home'),{transition: 'slideup',reverse:true});
    }
});
```

MyApp.UserFilterLayout

```
// The layout used for the user filter panel sliding up from bottom of page.
MyApp.UserFilterLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: '#userfilterlayout',
    //template: '#homepage-temp',
    regions: {
        selectedusers: '.selectedusers',
        allusers: '.allusers'
    },

    onShow: function () {
        console.log("userfilterlayout onShow");
        this.$el.trigger('create');
    }
});
```

[image: Facebook multi-friend selector UI]

Comment: You'd get a much better and more useful response on SO if you cut down the code to just the part you suspect of creating zombie views.

Comment: I'll trim it down and try that, thanks :)